# WinApi - Loop stops my program

Tags: c++, winapi, loops, visual-studio-2012

Code:

```
#include "CST CAL.h"
int SUSU()//Start Up
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData) != 0)
    {
        printf("WSASTATUP Falure: ", WSAGetLastError);
        Sleep(1200);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int SR()//Send and Recive Data
{
    return 0;
}
int DirX_Screen()//Render and Buffrer stuff and put on screen
{
    return 0;
}
int SHUT()//ShutDown Program
{
    return 0;
}
int GDI()//Get User Data Imput
{
    return 0;
}

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    //HERE IS CODE
        if (SUSU() != 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }int C = 0;
    do{while(GetForegroundWindow() == GetForegroundWindow()){
        int GeDI = GDI();
        int SeR = SR();
        int DirX = DirX_Screen();
        if( GeDI != 0 || SeR != 0 || DirX != 0){C = 1;}else{printf("FR Suc\n");}
        Sleep(0);
    }}while (C == 0);
    SHUT();
    //HERE IS END OF CODE SPACE
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_WIN32PROJECT1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32PROJECT1));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WIN32PROJECT1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32PROJECT1);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

This is originally a console application but then i use this template and just placed my code... my loop is supposed to print out the text but its not... it doesn't eve make the window. Please Help!

Comment: `while(GetForegroundWindow() == GetForegroundWindow()` ????

Comment: all that uppercase... it hurts...

Comment: Instead of `SUSU()//Start Up`, just, like, `StartUp()`. Or `start_up()`, which I prefer. Think about the readability of the **calling code**. Does it read like English with `SUSU` there? How about `start_up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is originally a console application but then i use this template
>   and just placed my code...

I wish things were that easy :)

You can't switch from console programming to the event driven one that easily. Maybe you should go through [this tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/).

> my loop is supposed to print out the text but its not...

In `winapi` we usually use [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display text, or you could change the text of the [`static control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or even pop a [`tooltip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is done usually **in response to a certain event**, like button press for an example.

> it doesn't eve make the window.

This happens because you have **an infinite `while` loop** before your call to `InitInstance( ... )`.

Your condition `while(GetForegroundWindow() == GetForegroundWindow())` is **always true** so you never leave the `while` loop, thus never reaching the code that creates the window ( `InitInstance( ... )` ).

> Please Help!

After you go through the tutorial I recommended above, you will be able to recode properly your application.

I do not know enough about what you are trying to do, but I will try to offer you some advice:

Put your initialization code in [`WM_CREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handler:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
        if( SUSU() != 0 )
            return (LRESULT)-1;
        else
            return (LRESULT)0;
    }
```

In your [`WM_DESTROY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should put your cleanup code ( note that [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sometimes **does not get called!** ):

```
case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        SHUT();
    }
```

Your `GDI()` should be a part of an event, maybe a button press-I don't know it is entirely up to you. The same goes for `SR()`. They will be processed in [`WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handler.

I do not know `DirectX` so I do not know where to put your `DirX_Screen()`, but you could leave fancy graphics last and concentrate on **functionality first**.

Hopefully this helps a little.

I strongly advise you to go through that tutorial and to learn to read `MSDN` documentation.

Best regards and good luck!